# When to refer another dimension table in a dimensional table

Tags: data-warehouse

I want to model contracts that clients have at an organization. Typically one client has one contract. One contract can have multiple machines with different starting and end dates.

The fact table will look something like this:

```
client_id (FK)
machine_id (FK)
contract_id (DD)
start_date
end_date
rate_per_month
```

I am wondering how the machine dimension table should look like. Should it also include the client_id? Seems somehow natural, but that seems to violate the 'no snowflake' principle.

```
machine_id
client_id (FK)(?)
type
model
brand
```

FK = foreign key, DD = degenerate dimension.

Kimballs book refers to outrigger dimensions which are okay, but I am not sure this counts as one.

Answer (score 1):

I *dimension* should define the attributes of the modeled entity and not attributes of some relationships of it (this is the role of *fact tables*).

So from this point of view I do not see any *natural arguments* to include `client_id` in the dimension table.

Note that you'll have to update this information in case of a re-assignment of the machine or after a churn of the client.

The relationship between the *machine* and the *client* is stored in your fact table.